# Changing Wordpress author name in database

Tags: php, users, author, phpmyadmin

I originally begun my wordpress site using a psudonym. Over the past few years I have been attributing my own name to all articles and have had the author name options switched off.

Now I'm changing theme I want to get the benefit of having the correct author name show up automatically against each new post, and if possible changing all the old posts to this new author name.

I'm wondering if it's possible to just change the name directly inside the PHP database, or if doing so would cause countless complications? I run the site alone and didn't want to have to set up umltiple accounts against my own wordpress site as the old author name will still exist.

Comment: In the wp_posts table every post has a post_author column with the user_id in it. If you change this id to your new user it simply shows the display name of that user. You could have also simply changed your display name in your old account

Answer (score 0):

Take a back up before trying anything! :) (I use the Duplicator plugin for that, if you don't already have a solution.

When you delete users in WordPress, it gives the option to attribute conent to another user. Would this suit your needs?

Comment: Yes. But does that mean adding a user under the new name and then deleting the old user?

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay. Yes, that is what I would consider in your situation, as it would be a tidy way to organise the posts, but you may have reasons for not wanting to change the old author identity?

Answer (score 0):

If your site has only one Author, then you can’t change or delete any Author, therefore, first of all, you need to add at least one user to your site. Then you can change the author name.

[There are many methods to change the author name in the WordPress website](https://octopusrecords.net/how-to/how-to-change-author-in-wordpress/) but the best method is Changing the Author Using Quick Edit in WordPress

First of all login into your WordPress website dashboard. Then click on all posts under the post section and choose the said post which you want to change the author name. Then click on the “Quick Edit,” the entire setting of the particular post will open. A drop-down list will now appear in this setting. This list includes all author names. You can choose the Author’s name whatever you want. After selecting, click on the update button. Now, the Author has changed.

[image]